# mootool event delay on specifed timing

Tags: mootools, mootools1.2

anyone come across a code that only fire event when the mouse enter the element for certain time ? but won't fire event if only hover or passed thru the element quickly..

Answer (score 1):

Using `setTimeout`, it's not the MooTools way. What you should use is the framework's methods:

```
var theDiv = $$('div')[0];
var foo = function(){
    theDiv.highlight();
};
var timer;

theDiv.addEvents({
    mouseenter: function() {
        timer = foo.delay(1000);
    },

    mouseleave: function() {
        $clear(timer);
    }
});​
```

See a working **example**: http://www.jsfiddle.net/oskar/SZsNT/

Answer (score 0):

```
var timer = null;
element.addEvents({
  mouseenter: function() {
    timer = setTimeout(foo, 5000);
  },

  mouseleave: function() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
  }

});
```

So `foo` will be called only if cursor was over element for 5 seconds

Comment: can i work around the code become like this ? but i not sure wat to replace with the foo..

        this.menu.addEvents({
            mouseenter: function (event) {
  timer = setTimeout(foo, 5000);

                obj.remain = [];
                obj.removeRemain(10)
            },
            mouseleave: function (event) {
  clearTimeout(timer);

                obj.remain.each(function (item) {
                    item.addClass(obj.options.remainClass)
                });
                obj.removeRemain(obj.options.remainTime)
            }
        });

Comment: `foo` is a function you what to be called in case cursor is over the element for 5 seconds